# Mediawiki + Lucene: How To Strip Markup?

Tags: lucene, mediawiki, markup

I have the Lucene search extension (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:Lucene-search) integrated with my mediawiki installation. Its all working really well, however- lucene seems to have indexed all the mediawiki /html markup as well and it is showing up in the results.

i.e. searching for "green" will return results with markup such as, style="background:green; color:white

Is there a way to strip the search results of all the markup? I believe wikipedia uses the same search plugin, how are they doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to transform the raw wiki markup before indexing it with Lucene. When dealing with pure XML content, it's possible to just use an XSL transform with `<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>` to extract the text content.

I'm afraid that won't work for wiki markup, but maybe you can capture the page post-HTML transformation?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to part of the problem.  The following change will remove HTML markup from the search results.  I have not been able to remove Wikitext markup yet.  Any tips on that would be appreciated.  Note that I do not use the Lucene search extension.

- Open /includes/search/SearchEngine.php
- In that file, there is a class defined - SearchResult
- SearchResult.getTextSnippet() contains the code to format the search results
- SearchResult->mText contains the text blurb from the search results
  To fix the problem, simply go into SearchEngine.php and find the method called getTextSnippet(), then add the following line before the "if":

$this->mText = strip_tags( $this->mText );

I found this solution on this random Wiki: http://www.myrandomwiki.com/wiki/MediaWiki_Notes#Strip_HTML_From_Search_Results